# How to compare two sets in MySQL or SQL SERVER?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, relational-database, relational-algebra

In this University Database:

```
CREATE TABLE Stud(
    [S#] INT PRIMARY KEY,
    Sname NVARCHAR(50),
    City NVARCHAR(50),
    GPA FLOAT,
    [Clg#] SMALLINT
);

CREATE TABLE Sec(
    [Sec#] SMALLINT,
    [C#] INT,
    [S#] INT,
    Semester SMALLINT,
    Pname NVARCHAR(50),
    Score NVARCHAR(30),
    PRIMARY KEY([Sec#], [C#], Semester)
);

Stud
Sec#,C#,S#,Semester,Pname,Score
1724,10172,1133848,161,Sullivan,62%
1516,51516,4182532,152,Cooper,73%
1747,10174,1133848,152,Sullivan,75%
1747,10174,2130502,153,Sullivan,55%
1540,10156,2203305,161,Sullivan,60%
1540,10156,1133848,181,Sullivan,87%
1540,10156,2203305,182,Sullivan,40%
1802,10156,4182532,192,Sullivan,60%

Sec
S#,Sname,City,GPA,Clg#
1133848,Parker,NY,3.8,10
2130502,White,Chicago,2.8,10
2203305,Gardner,LA,3.5,1
3120504,West,Boston,3.85,4
3166801,Warren,Seattle,3.2,5
4182532,Rogers,NY,3.3,5
4209836,Allen,Austin,1.5,6
```

I have this question:

Find names and IDs of students who have had **ALL** the courses that teacher Sullivan has taught.

I can easily find the answer with relational algebra:

```
Π #,,#( ⋈ ) ÷ Π c#(σ pname="Sullivan" (sec))
```

1. How do I implement the Division operator in SQL?

And our teacher gave us this answer for SQL SERVER:

```
 .#, 
 , 
 .# = .#
  .#, 
 #  ( DISTINCT #
 
WHERE pname ="Sullivan");
```

And from the slides of our online class, this is what they mean by `CONTAINS`:

[image: Contains]

2. But from what I have googled, the `contains` function has nothing to do with sets, it seems to be a full-indexed test searching function. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

After a while, I came up with this solution:

```
SELECT Stud.* FROM Stud WHERE S# IN
(SELECT S#/*,COUNT(DISTINCT C#) as c*/ FROM Sec WHERE Pname='Sullivan' GROUP BY S# HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT C#)=
(SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT [C#]) FROM Sec WHERE Pname='Sullivan'));
```

Comment: Your teacher should really learn explicit `JOIN` syntax.

Comment: Was this query written on a stone tablet?!

Comment: And that query is weird in many ways. Can you change to another class?

Comment: Can you elaborate? Please and thank you.

Comment: Is this query really provide to you by a teacher ? He should not be teaching. This query has so many problems I don't know where to begin

Comment: The division operator has no direct equivalent in SQL. Usually work around it by using sub queries and comparing COUNT()'s.

Comment: _contains function has nothing to do with sets_ Correct - it is based on full-text indexing. Your teacher is wasting your time and money if that solution is supposed to work "correctly" in SQL Server. This is the second time you have posted a question like this - either use the database engine your teacher does or find another class.

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Paraphrase or quote from other text. Give just what you need & relate it to your problem. Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image.

Comment: Relational division & related queries in SQL is a faq. . Before considering posting please read the manual & google any error message & many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular names/strings/numbers, 'site:stackoverflow.com' & tags; read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. Reflect your research. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts. PS Since you have a version in an SQL, how are you stuck? [mre]

Comment: @philipxy Hello I added the text, but as you can see it doesn't look good. Also, I mentioned relational algebra to explain my problem better, I'm a university student and I was trying to show my point of view, I googled a lot before asking this question but the questions on SO were askers asking for their own use cases, there weren't any general question that explains this.

Comment: You don't need the images once you have text. And the tables should be code (DDL & DML) when part of a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input as code; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL (including constraints & indexes) & input as code formatted as a table. PS [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/3404097) [What is the policy here on homework?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/18242/266284)

Comment: @philipxy This wasn't a homework question, I had this course last semester.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Gag. This would seem to answer the question:

```
SELECT stud.s#, stud.sname
FROM stud s JOIN
     sec
     ON stud.s# = sec.s# 
WHERE secs.pname = 'Sullivan'
GROUP BY stud.s#, sname
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT sec.c#) = (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT sec2.c# FROM sec sec2 WHERE sec2.pname = 'Sullivan');
```

Let me say that I'm not impressed with the teacher:

- *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.
- *Always* use proper, explicit, **standard**, readable `JOIN` syntax.
- `CONTAINS()` is a SQL Server full-text function.  It doesn't exist in MySQL.  And I have not heard of its use as a set operator.
- Spaces after the `.` is non-standard . . . and I would suggest table aliases as well.